# Synchronizing javascript action between two people

Tags: javascript, time, bookmarklet, same-origin-policy

I'm trying to create a javascript bookmarklet that two people press such that a video autostarts at the same time, for synchronous viewing. Most of my experience is in java, not js, so I'm completely lost as to how to approach this.

I have already figured out how to play the video, but I'm not sure how to approach the timing. I was planning to have both people click the bookmarklet, and the script would reach out to some online clock, and would autoplay at the nearest minute.  I found [this simple time API](http://www.timeapi.org/utc/now), but I'm not sure how to retrieve this text, since it is external from the video website.

I did some research and read that it isn't possible due to same origin policy. Is there any way around this? Is there some other way to approach this, or is my idea just scrapped?

Comment: If you're talking about getting them to play at *exactly* the same time, given that the two people could be right next to each other, or could be on the other side of the world, then this is a near-impossible task.  You need to think about clock skew, latency, etc. On the other hand, it may be doable if you can specify a degree of tolerance.

Comment: I'm not thinking it has to that exact exact, but preferably within 1-3 seconds delay. I tried using system time but I found that it varied up to a minute difference between computers.

Comment: You'll find that in general, you cannot trust a user's clock to be set correctly *at all*. Even if they are correctly synchronized, they could be off by several minutes depending on how accurate the servers are that they're synchronizing with and how far apart those servers are from each other.  Read about clock strata.

Comment: You *can* get the current time from a central server, but without some fancy footwork you can't be guaranteed that two different computers will get the exact same time, due to the delays involved in network transmittal.   I've yet to see a good fully-implemented NTP client for JavaScript yet.  All implementations I'm aware of are SNTP only, or just HTTP - like the one you linked to.

Comment: You can *attempt* to use that time api to decided how to coordinate your events, but in the end you'll find it to be inconsistently off a few seconds here or there -  due to the nature of the problem.

Comment: WRT the origin policy problem - look into "CORS".

Comment: The things I'm reading about CORS is way beyond my level of comprehension right now. How would I simply just get the plain data from the API?